# How do I get my reset button to work more than once?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created an app with a reset button that reloads the page as a way to "reset" the values. The problem is the page only resets once. After the new page is loaded, the button doesn't work again.

Here's the button XAML:

```
<Button Name="refresh" Click="ResetButton_Click" >Reset</Button>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
private void ResetButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
       nav.Navigate(new Uri("FEModel.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is enough info or not. I just want the button to reset the page whenever it's pushed, not just the once. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure you can navigate two tiimes to the same URI. Why not reseting in VM?

Comment: Have you tried `this.NavigationService.Refresh();` ?

Answer (score 1):

> If the content identified by the URI is the current content, it is not downloaded again. [[Microsoft Docs]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigate?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Navigation_NavigationService_Navigate_System_Uri_#remarks)

To remove the current content you have to navigate to `null` before you can reload the actual page:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(null);
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("FEModel.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

or instead directly call

```
NavigationService.Refresh();
```